# Mostrar ubicaciones cercanas de los eventos guardados en función de mi ubicación actual android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Estoy creando una aplicación en la que muestro en los recyclerView "Eventos" a los que los usuarios se pueden apuntar.

Estos eventos tienen un mapView con una ubicación donde se realizará.

Me gustaría que en función de la ubicación del usuario me mostrase solo las actividades que tuvieran una ubicación más cercana, es decir, que si mi ubicación actual es Murcia me muestre en primer lugar los eventos que tengan una ubicación cercana a Murcia y no me muestre los eventos de Lugo.

¿Como podría filtrar en función de la ubicación? ¿A través de la latitud y longitud?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo una implementación similar, yo consumo una API RESTFul y ahí es donde obtengo la información una vez obtenida recorro la información y consumo un web service de Google (documentación oficial [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start)) donde lat1 y long1 son la ubicación que da el GPS del telefono y lat2 y long2 deberían de ser la ubicación de tus eventos, el web service te regresa un arreglo con diferentes datos entre ellos la distancia. Ordenas los valores y lo regresas ya ordenados los eventos listos para mostrar en el RecyclerView.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$lat1.",".$long1."&destinations=".$lat2.",".$long2."&mode=driving&key=APIKEY"
```

Se me ocurre algo así:

```
eventosDistancia = array();
foreach(eventos as evento){
   //Aquí se manda a llamar la función que ejecute el consumo del web service anterior
   eventosDiscantia[]=calcularDistancia(latitudTel,longitudTel,evento->latitud,evento->latitud);
}
//Ordenas el arreglo de menor a mayor y lo regresas para pintarlo en el RecyclerView
```

Comment: Me serviría para Android? No soy muy experto en este tema y no sabría muy bien cómo llamar al link que me estás diciendo. Y luego el calcularDistancia como sería?